# Changing the prefab an object is associated with in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the prefab my object `playerPawn` is associated with. I tried to do it with this code:

```
int i = 0;

PrefabUtility.DisconnectPrefabInstance(this.playerPawn);
PrefabUtility.ConnectGameObjectToPrefab (this.playerPawn, this.playerPawnPrefabs [i]); 

Debug.Log(this.playerPawnPrefabs[i]);

PrefabUtility.ResetToPrefabState(this.playerPawn);
```

However, the last line is throwing this error:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been
>   destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should
>   either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

The `Debug.Log()` showed me that `this.playerPawnPrefabs[i]` contains the GameObject I'm expecting, so I don't understand where that error comes from.

Comment: It says the gameobject is destroyed. Try debug.log:ging the this.playerPawn between every PrefabUtility-usage?

Comment: Using `Debug.Log(this.playerPawn) ` show me that the GameObject is destroyed after the call to  `ConnectGameObjectToPrefab `.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.playerPawnPrefabs [i]` is not null?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. But hold on, I'm trying to find another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to reassign the return of ConnectGameObjectToPrefab method to your playerPawn object:

```
this.playerPawn = PrefabUtility.ConnectGameObjectToPrefab (this.playerPawn, this.playerPawnPrefabs [i]);
```

Then you can call ResetToPrefabState method.